# Easy way to fill in missing data

Tags: java, r, excel, pivot-table, data-mining

I have a table with results from an optimization algorithm. I have 100 runs. X represents the time and is only stored when an improvement is stored. So I have  missing x-es.

```
x1; y1  ; x2 ; y2
1 ; 100 ; 1  ; 150
4 ; 90  ; 2  ; 85
7 ; 85  ; 10 ; 60
10; 80  ;
```

This is just a csv. I am looking for a method to easily process this. As want to calculate averages at each x-value. So the average at x = 4, needs to take into account that for run 2, y at 4 is 85.

Any easy way to do this with excel. Or read it in in java or R? (I will be plotting the agerage with R's ggplot).

So the expected output would look like this:

```
x1; y1  ; x2 ; y2
1 ; 100 ; 1  ; 150
2 ; 100 ; 2  ; 85
4 ; 90  ; 4  ; 85
7 ; 85  ; 7  ; 85
10; 80  ;10 ; 60
```

--UPDATE

I have applied agstudy's answer below. This is my script:

```
library(ggplot2)
 library(zoo)

data1 = read.table("rundata1", sep= " ", col.names=c("tm1","score1","current1"))
data2 = read.table("rundata1", sep= " ", col.names=c("tm2","score2","current2"))

newdata<- merge(data1[,1:2],data2[,1:2],by=1,all=T)
newdata <- newdata[!is.na(newdata$tm1),]
newdata$score1 <- zoo::na.locf(newdata$score1)
newdata$score2 <- zoo::na.locf(newdata$score2)
```

Almost working now. Only have an error:

```
newdata$score2 <- zoo::na.locf(newdata$score2)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "score2", value = c(40152.6, 40152.6,  : 
  replacement has 11767 rows, data has 11768
```

Comment: can you please clarify on expected output?

Comment: Sorry you are right. I have added a sample output to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, in R you can do this in 2 steps. First you merge your 2 runs, then you fill the missing values with the last no missing. I am using `na.locf` from the zoo package for this.

```
xx <- read.table(text='x1; y1  ; x2 ; y2
1 ; 100 ; 1  ; 150
4 ; 90  ; 2  ; 85
7 ; 85  ; 10 ; 60
10; 80  ;',sep=';',fill=TRUE,header=TRUE)

dm <- merge(xx[,1:2],xx[,3:4],by=1,all=T)
dm <- dm[!is.na(dm$x1),]
dm$y1 <- zoo::na.locf(dm$y1)
dm$y2 <- zoo::na.locf(dm$y2)
dm
  x1  y1  y2
1  1 100 150
2  2 100  85
3  4  90  85
4  7  85  85
5 10  80  60
```

Comment: I really like your approach, yet, some of the x2 datapoints seem to be missing. Could that be? I will put my code in the question.

Comment: @dorien i don't think this can happen sice I am using `merge` with `all=TRUE` option.

Comment: Curious, I guess I am  missing something simple in the script above. Your example works perfectly in contrast.

Comment: Ok, I had a very silly input error, was reading the same file twice! Now I only  have this error: newdata$score2 <- zoo::na.locf(newdata$score2)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "score2", value = c(40152.6, 40152.6,  : 
  replacement has 11767 rows, data has 11768

Comment: Perhaps because there is an empty line at the back?

Comment: I have moved the error discussion to a new question. Your suggestiong of using this helped me though and I am sure it will work once I get through the errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038887/r-merging-data-error-in-fix-byby-x-x

Answer (score 1):

With Excel you might use VLOOKUP if first you have a column of all unique sorted `x` values ascending (one column seems sufficient?) and for `y` something like:

```
=VLOOKUP($F2,A:B,2)
```

(`=VLOOKUP($F2,C:D,2)` for `y2`) each copied down to suit.

[image: SO21912834 first example]

Alternatively, if you are prepared to change your source data layout along the lines shown`*` then you might use a PivotTable, copy that with Paste Special…, Values, put something in the cell immediately to the right of `Values`, select the `y1` and `y2` columns and Go To Special, Blanks, `=`, Up, `Ctrl`+`Enter`.

`*` or remove the numbers from the `x` labels and use multiple consolidation ranges instead.

[image: SO21912834 second example]